# Cassandra: how to filter more then one column

Tags: cassandra

Is it possible to filter more than one column?

I want to give the user an option to filter informations, all written in one table. I add Indexes to my table but with these it was not possible to filter more then one column.

Values could also be null, so it is not possible to define them as clustering columns, is it?

Answer (score 0):

There are several types of queries you can do in CQL that return more than one row.

The most common and efficient are range queries based on a clustering key.

Another method is to use the IN clause with a SELECT statement.

But Cassandra has a lot of restrictive rules on when you are allowed to do these types of queries and on which types of columns.

See more details here: [A deep look at the CQL WHERE clause](http://www.datastax.com/dev/blog/a-deep-look-to-the-cql-where-clause)

Comment: But it is not possible to filter non cluster keys? Not all values of data if want filter are set, so I could not set them as cluster key, could i?

Comment: Compared to a relational database, the ability to do ad hoc queries in CQL is much more limited. You need to design your schema for the queries you want to do.